# SQL stuck on and else syntax error

Tags: t-sql, if-statement, while-loop, sql-server-2012

I'm running into an ELSE syntax error and would really appreciate a 2nd set of eyes to show me what is wrong! I'm using SSMS v17.3. The message I am receiving is:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 98
>
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ELSE'.

Line 98 is the last ELSE before the go. About 6 lines above the end of the entire statement. Thank you in advanced!

```
DECLARE @GroupID uniqueidentifier
DECLARE @fCompID int
DECLARE @fPropID int
DECLARE @fCompGUID uniqueidentifier

Set @GroupID = 'E63DC5E7-C8C8-4EA3-B1BF-75712DD83EF4'
SET @fCompID = '0'
SET @fPropID = '0'

WHILE @fCompID <= '999'
    BEGIN
    IF @fCompID = (SELECT fID FROM tSCCompany WHERE fID = @fCompID)
        SET @fCompGUID = (SELECT fCompanyID FROM tSCCompany WHERE fID = @fCompID)
        WHILE @fPropID <='999'
            BEGIN
            IF @fPropID = (SELECT fID FROM tSCProperty WHERE fID = @fPropID AND fCompanyID = @fCompGUID)
                BEGIN
                INSERT INTO zPropTest(fGroupID, fPropertyID)
                    Select @GroupID, (select fPropertyID from tSCProperty where fID = @fPropID AND fCompanyID = @fCompGUID)
                SET @fPropID = @fPropID + 1
                END
            ELSE
                BEGIN
                SET @fPropID = @fPropID + 1
                END
            END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
        SET @fCompID = @fCompID + 1
        SET @fPropID = '0'
        END
    END
GO
```

Comment: you are forgetting indicate the first if block with BEGIN AND END. try writting BEGIN before `SET @fCompGUID = (SELECT fCompanyID FROM tSCCompany WHERE fID = @fCompID)` and END after the end `while`

Comment: Aside: It looks like you have learned a procedural language and you're applying the lessons to SQL. SQL is best used by processing sets of data and allowing the database to optimize the actual processing, e.g. using `insert into zPropTest ( fGroupId, fPropertyId ) select @GroupId, tSCPropertyId from tSCProperty where fCompanyId = @fCompGUID where fPropertyId <= 999;`. You are also mixing data types, e.g. `@fCompId < '999'` compares an `int` with a string according to the rules for [data type precedence](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql).

Answer (score 0):

I think that you missing the TOP 1

```
DECLARE @GroupID uniqueidentifier
DECLARE @fCompID int
DECLARE @fPropID int
DECLARE @fCompGUID uniqueidentifier

Set @GroupID = 'E63DC5E7-C8C8-4EA3-B1BF-75712DD83EF4'
SET @fCompID = '0'
SET @fPropID = '0'

WHILE @fCompID <= '999'
    BEGIN
        IF @fCompID = (SELECT fID FROM tSCCompany WHERE fID = @fCompID) -- Need top 1?
            SET @fCompGUID = (SELECT fCompanyID FROM tSCCompany WHERE fID = @fCompID) -- Need top 1?
            WHILE @fPropID <='999'
                BEGIN
                    IF @fPropID = (SELECT fID FROM tSCProperty WHERE fID = @fPropID AND fCompanyID = @fCompGUID) -- Need top 1?
                        BEGIN
                            INSERT INTO zPropTest(fGroupID, fPropertyID)
                                Select @GroupID, 
                                    (select top 1 fPropertyID from tSCProperty 
                                        where fID = @fPropID AND fCompanyID = @fCompGUID)
                            SET @fPropID = @fPropID + 1
                        END
                    ELSE
                        BEGIN
                            SET @fPropID = @fPropID + 1
                        END
                END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                SET @fCompID = @fCompID + 1
                SET @fPropID = '0'
            END
    END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are missing one of the begin blocks. Please try like below:

```
DECLARE @GroupID uniqueidentifier
DECLARE @fCompID int
DECLARE @fPropID int
DECLARE @fCompGUID uniqueidentifier

Set @GroupID = 'E63DC5E7-C8C8-4EA3-B1BF-75712DD83EF4'
SET @fCompID = '0'
SET @fPropID = '0'
BEGIN-- MISSING!!
WHILE @fCompID <= '999'
    BEGIN
    IF @fCompID = (SELECT fID FROM tSCCompany WHERE fID = @fCompID)

        SET @fCompGUID = (SELECT fCompanyID FROM tSCCompany WHERE fID = @fCompID)
        WHILE @fPropID <='999'
            BEGIN
            IF @fPropID = (SELECT fID FROM tSCProperty WHERE fID = @fPropID AND fCompanyID = @fCompGUID)
                BEGIN
                INSERT INTO zPropTest(fGroupID, fPropertyID)
                    Select @GroupID, (select fPropertyID from tSCProperty where fID = @fPropID AND fCompanyID = @fCompGUID)
                SET @fPropID = @fPropID + 1
                END
            ELSE
                BEGIN
                SET @fPropID = @fPropID + 1
                END
            END
      END-- MISSING
    ELSE
        BEGIN
        SET @fCompID = @fCompID + 1
        SET @fPropID = '0'
        END
    END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

You need block indicators for your `If` statement.  See the two lines that I added

```
DECLARE @GroupID uniqueidentifier
DECLARE @fCompID int
DECLARE @fPropID int
DECLARE @fCompGUID uniqueidentifier

Set @GroupID = 'E63DC5E7-C8C8-4EA3-B1BF-75712DD83EF4'
SET @fCompID = '0'
SET @fPropID = '0'

WHILE @fCompID <= '999'
    BEGIN
    IF @fCompID = (SELECT fID FROM tSCCompany WHERE fID = @fCompID)
        Begin  --  I added this
            SET @fCompGUID = (SELECT fCompanyID FROM tSCCompany WHERE fID = @fCompID)
            WHILE @fPropID <='999'
                BEGIN
                IF @fPropID = (SELECT fID FROM tSCProperty WHERE fID = @fPropID AND fCompanyID = @fCompGUID)
                    BEGIN
                    INSERT INTO zPropTest(fGroupID, fPropertyID)
                        Select @GroupID, (select fPropertyID from tSCProperty where fID = @fPropID AND fCompanyID = @fCompGUID)
                    SET @fPropID = @fPropID + 1
                    END
                ELSE
                    BEGIN
                    SET @fPropID = @fPropID + 1
                    END
                End
        End  --  I added this, too 
    ELSE
        BEGIN
        SET @fCompID = @fCompID + 1
        SET @fPropID = '0'
        END
    END
GO
```